# How to split text between separator into multiple files?

Tags: bash, text-processing, split

I have a text file contaning the following:

```
"random
textA"
"random
random
textB"
```

The separator is `"`

How can I split the containt into multiple file as follow using a bash command?

**File 1 :**

```
random
textA
```

**File 2 :**

```
random
random
textB
```

I came into examples using `csplit` or `awk` but they does not cover this text layout.

Comment: Is that the only text in the file?

Comment: yes only text in the file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR%2==0{ print >("File " ++i) }' RS='"' infile
```

`RS` defines `"` as record separator and `NR` is the record number. If the record number was modulo of 2 (because we have another first `"` for records), then print the current record `$0` into a `File #`.

Comment: This is IMO the best answer as it works even if other lines exist between `"$` and  the next `^"`.

Comment: don't need the begin just use `++i` instead of `i++`.Could be shortened to `awk 'NR%2==0{ print >"File "++i }' RS='"' file`

Comment: @Jidder Uh,yes. thank you. updated with that,

Comment: My goodness - spaces in file names? May you be forgiven.

Answer (score 5):

If the opening quote is always at the beginning of the line, csplit will work just fine like this:

```
bash$ csplit /tmp/data '/^"/'
```

That produces files called xx00, etc. Note, your example removes the quotation marks and this doesn't. You'd need a command line sed to do that:

```
bash$ for file in xx* ; do { sed 's/^"//;s/"$//;' ${file} >x${file}; } ; done
```

Comment: With `coreutils csplit`: `csplit -z filesample '/^"/' {*}` so as to split more than once and ignore the first piece (`xx00`) which will always be empty (for the given text sample).

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -v RS='"[[:space:]]*"' '
{sub(/^"|"[[:space:]]*$/, "");print > "output." ++n; close("output." n)}' file.txt
```

Comment: An alternative: `awk -v RS='"' '!/^[[:space:]]*$/ {print > "output." n++; close...}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
awk -v RS=\" -v ORS= \
  '{ sub(/^\n*/,"");sub(/\n*$/,""); };
  /^\n*$/ { next;};
  { if(strcnt==0) { print $0 >"file1"; strcnt++;} else
  { print $0 >"file2"; }; }' file
```